# Adobe javascript: Need to get value of a field (SCORE) and return text (PASS/FAIL)

Tags: javascript, text, numbers, adobe

I do not have any JavaScript experience and am hoping that someone can assist me with a Adobe form calculation.
I am creating a Pass/Fail scorecard that will take a value from a field (Calc_OScore) and then return a word (Perfect!, Pass, Fail) based on the score.

Due to my lack of experience and ignorance, my attempts to make this work have been nothing more than copy/paste trial and error from others' scripts and experiences.
I've tried this:

```js
var text;
if ("Calc_OScore" == "16") {
 text = "PERFECT!!";
} else if ("Calc_OScore" > "11") {
 text = "PASS";
} else {
 text = "FAIL";
}
```

And one of these:

```js
var int1=this.getField("E_score").value;
var int2=this.getField("S_score").value;
var int3=this.getField("P_score").value;
var int4=this.getField("C_score").value;
var tSum = (int1+int2+int3+int4);
var rVal = 'NULL';
if(tSum===16){
 rVal='PERFECT SCORE!';
}else if(tSum>11){
 rVal='NOT PERFECT BUT OKAY!';
}else{
 rVal='FAIL';
}
return rVal;
```

But I'm pretty sure that's not JavaScript.

Can anyone help out here?  If it makes it easier to understand what I'm trying to accomplish, here's what my formula in Excel looked like:
=IFS(F31=16,"PERFECT!",F31>11,"PASS",TRUE,"FAIL")

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

I have two tips. For starters `("Calc_OScore" == "16")` will never be true. If it's in quotes, it's a string.

I'm not super familiar with JavaScript within the context of Adobe, but I have a feeling your second example is a bit closer. My hunch is that `var tSum = (int1+int2+int3+int4);` is correct but all the values (`int1`, `int2`, etc.) might be strings. You can coerce strings into integers with `parseInt` like so `parseInt(int1)`.